# How to get "Copy as cURL" in the terminal?

Tags: curl, cookie

In the web browser, there is "Web Developer" mode aka "Inspect Elements, also there is 'Network' tab in the Developer Mode, for monitoring webpage loading time for each file.
I can also copy the responded cURL headers with the menu called "Copy as cURL".

So with that cURL headers and cookies info, I can perfectly emulate the exact same situation on the other machine, so the host treats me as I am on the same machine and the same browser when I paste in the terminal with the copied curl command.

Now I wanted to make that job of dragging the mouse and click a few areas plus right-click to get that "Copy as cURL" clipboard data for the terminal uses. (the reason why 'Copy as cURL' features is there).

P.S. I'm not talking about -I or -i tags, I want the result cURL to call the same page result displayed. So the script uses it right away.
"Copy as cURL" includes almost everything. but I could not find a way to do it in the terminal.
Is there a way to get that same "Copy as cURL" copy? or is there an option with an executable Linux browser parameter to achieve that data?

EDIT: steps to reproduce my problem.

1. in the terminal: `firefox "https://somewebsite"` (or chromium web browser)
   then the GUI will open up the firefox with the website and loads all the page and has "copy as cURL" information.
2. I want the "Copy as cURL" data, that the chromium has in the "network tab" of "Inspect Elements"

Comment: Which web browser? Firefox? How would your script know *which* resource to "copy as curl"? Usually a web site will call a lot of resources.

Comment: It works the same on Firefox, Chrome and Opera, I would say index file in most of cases. So index file copy as curl.

Comment: while it works similar for the GUI it might be very different to emulate that from CLI...

Comment: What if you extract all of the links from the main web page, and put `curl ` in front of them and  add a referer, a user agent and the `--compressed` flag? That could be scripted. Or isn't it that simple?

Comment: @Jos --referer might be interesting to try, could you also give me an example curl command?

Comment: Actually, I did just what you described: go to one of the links under the Network tab (in Google Chrome DevTools) and do `Copy -> as Curl`. Then I pasted it in a text file and found the `--referer`, `--user-agent` and `--compressed` flags.

Comment: BTW I noticed there is also a `copy all to Curl` option, which generates separate `curl` statements for all links.

Comment: @Jos I know, as I described, I am looking to make that as a script. not in GUI.

Comment: `wget` has some useful options for downloading a page and all of the links contained therein, which is what you may need.